# vue table transition occurs from bottom not from top

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vue-transitions

I have a table and a data coming from websocket every 5 seconds. I added this data to table as a row bu using unshift() method. Now I should add transition when websocket data adding to table.
This is the code that websocket data added to the table:

```
getSocketTransactions(val) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        this.$store.state.transaction.transactionsList.unshift(val[i]);
}
```

These are the code where I use transition:

```
<transition-group
          :name="isActive ? 'transactionAnimation' : null"
          tag="tbody"
          class="list-group"
        >
// some code
</transition-group>
```

The problem is the data added to the top of the table but the transition occurs from bottom. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How does your `transactionAnimation` animation look like?

You define the direction of the animation in your transition css like this:

```
.transactionAnimation-enter-from,
.transactionAnimation-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-30px); /* -30px for animation from top, 30px for animation from bottom */
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-yp85fn

Comment: .transactionAnimation-enter-active {
  transition: opacity ease 0.55s, transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.transactionAnimation-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
}

.slide-fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

Comment: I've added a Demo, so you can check how it should behave

Comment: I find the issue and fix it. It depends on the :key in for loop. https://codepen.io/megacromulent/pen/wEzWNL -> this helps me